# Return List of values of arrays only once in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a JSON Object that looks like this :

```
   "data": [
    {"Name": "First", "Color":"Red"},
    { "Name": "First", "Color":"Blue"},
    {"Name": "First", "Color":"Red"},
    { "Name": "First", "Color":"Pink"},
    { "Name": "First", "Color":"Red"},
    {"Name": "First", "Color":"Blue"},
    { "Name": "Dont Show", "Color":"Red"}

]
```

I want to create a Typescript function that will return only distinct values of the field Color..so : Red,Blue,Pink (once).
This will be in a pipe,
so then I can bind thields in a dropdown and have a dropdown of colors.

So I will have :

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor="let data of data | custompipe">
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{data.color}}</a>
```

How do I do this in typescript ?
How do I get Colors appeared in the object, but only once.

Comment: filter pipes are not recommended. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: In your sample (where it says Color..so: Red,Blue,Pink) you should reformat that with code chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `uniqBy` method in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor="let data of data | customPipe">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{data.color}}</a>
</div>

transform(records: Array<any>): any {
    return _.uniqBy(records, 'Color');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2abazs)

```
import { Component, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'custompipe' })
export class Custompipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[]): any[] {
    let colors : any[]= [];
    return data.filter((el) => {
      if (colors.indexOf(el.Color) == -1){
          colors.push(el.Color);
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    })

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Red" },
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Blue" },
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Red" },
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Pink" },
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Red" },
    { "Name": "First", "Color": "Blue" },
    { "Name": "Dont Show", "Color": "Red" }

  ]
}
```

template :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu"  *ngFor="let d of data| custompipe ">
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{d.Color}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data changes, other answers won't work. That's why you are better to do it manually, not with pipes. Or use impure pipe.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor="let color of colors">
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{color}}</a>    


this.colors= [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Color))];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'distinct'}) export default class {
  tranform<T>(values: T[], keyOrKeySelector?: keyof T | ((x: T) => any): T[] {
    const keySelector =
        typeof keyOrKeySelector === 'function'
          ? keyOrKeySelector
          : ((x: T) => JSON.stringify(x[keyOrKeySelector]));

      const results = values.reduce((distinct, value) => ({
        ...distinct,
        [keySelector(value)]: value
      }), {});

      return Object.values(results);
  }
}
```

Usage without key or function (uses `JSON.stringify` to do a structural comparison)

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data | distinct"
   class="dropdown-menu"
   aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{item.color}}</a>
 </div>
```

Usage with key, selects distinct items by color

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data | distinct: 'color'"
   class="dropdown-menu"
   aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{item.color}}</a>
 </div>
```

Usage with projection, selects distinct items by arbitrary criteria

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data | distinct: toId"
   class="dropdown-menu"
   aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{item.color}}</a>
 </div>
```

where `toId` is in you view model

```
@Component({}) export default class {

  toId = (item: {id: number, name: "First", color: "Red"}) => ({item.id, item.color});

}
```